# Logger not displaying output in editor when script executed from Google Site

Tags: google-apps-script

This used to work for me fine, but now only get log output when script executed from editor which isn't helpful when GUI is involved.  Same prob was earlier documented here:
http://productforums.google.com/d/topic/apps-script/5o5PBbH75Yk/discussion

Answer (score 0):

You should star this issue [I'd seen this posted](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1601)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the concurrent use of Browser.msgBox.

Comment: I believe the initial poster had used the browser.msgbox to show his function was being run.  Review my comment that includes a video illustrating the failure using the delivered example code.

Comment: Sorry, I saw other posts that were discussing a conflict between the two.  I starred issue 1601.  I think my prob is more basic: the editor reports no logs found unless the script is run from the editor.  Get no logs when running from the Google site.  Worked like a charm before.  Seems like a basic config/connectivity issue that others must have experienced.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to [issue 1502](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1502) which appears end of june this year. Please consider to vote for it if you find it relevant.

In the meantime I use a textArea widget in which I show data I want to log... not always very nice looking but *efficient* ;-)